# VSTS git submodule reference error

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-build-task

I have a CoreApp project (CoreApp) and a Project1 that depends on the CoreApp Project. Thanks to someone from MSFT on SO, previously I was able to get this compiled with VSTS git using the (CoreApp)submodule under Project1. However, now in Project1, whenever I reference a model in the CoreApp Project (eg., a AppUser class), I get the build error - "The type or namespace name 'AppUser' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)" error. I read some SO posts and changed not only the folder name but also the CoreApp Model namespace in the CoreApp project, and now I got a different error - "The type or namespace name 'CoreAppModels' does not exist in the namespace 'CoreAppApp' (are you missing an assembly reference?) [d:\a\1\Project1\Project1.csproj]. I also continue to get the previous error. It seems to me that the build process is not picking up the CoreApp assembly, or the updated code, but I did see that the CoreApp project was pulled down during the build process.

All of this works and builds fine on my PC. I verified that on VSTS, I have the CoreApp file with the hash, and the .gitmodules with the entry -

```
[submodule "Project1/CoreApp"]
    path = Project1/CoreApp
    url = https://name.visualstudio.com/_git/CoreApp
```

Again, I do see that the CoreApp is pulled down during the build -

```
 Copying file from "obj\Release\CoreApp.dll" to "bin\CoreApp.dll".
 CoreApp -> d:\a\1\s\Project1\CoreApp\bin\CoreApp.dll
```

Does the build process on VSTS pull down the latest submodule code when doing a build? Does anyone know what I am doing wrong? I am pulling my hair out and any help is appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Please check your VSTS build definition:

In Get source step -> show the advanced settings -> make sure the **Checkout submodules** is selected -> Save.

[image]

[image]

Then build your `project1` again, the `Project1\CoreApp\bin\CoreApp.dll` will be found from submodule.

To update sumodules in main repo, you can add a **Command Line task** after Get sources step:

Tool: `git`

Arguments: `submodule foreach "git pull origin master"`

[image]

Comment: I do have the checkbox selected and also the Recursion level set.

Comment: I think I know the issue, but I don't know how to fix it. Previously I updated the submodule and checked it in. However, the file with the SHA hash (CoreApp) that is sitting in VSTS Project1 repo is still pointing at the old version of CoreApp. How do I update this file to the updated CoreApp version?

Comment: To update submodule, you just need to add a command line task, detail settings in my answer, you can have a try.